# Is there any way to change where Material-UI adds style tag html elements?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Material-UI adds generated style tags to the `<header />` which is of course a standard place for styles, however I need my style tags to be added in a different html element.

I'm looking for a way to transition a legacy CodeIgniter PHP application to React. I have a plan but the issue is that this legacy application is using bootstrap which is messing with my React components.

The plan is to reset all styles in a div and render React components in it. something like:

```
<div class="clearcss">
    <div>
        <style type="text/css"></style> // material ui style tags
        <div id="react-component"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately because Material ui adds all of its styles to the header Material ui styles are also reset, but if I could change where material ui places style tags then I think I could make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in JSS [documentation](https://cssinjs.org/setup/?v=v10.3.0) I found examples that show how to specify insertion points outside `<head />`.

Together with Ryan's comment pointing to material ui [documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#insertionpoint) I was able to achieve what I wanted.

JSS supports two ways of specifying a custom insertion point for styles:

1. By adding an html comment (e.g. `<!-- custom-jss-insertion-point -->`). This is only supported for insertion points in the `<head>`.
2. By specifying an element (e.g. `insertionPoint: document.getElementById("custom-jss-insertion-point")`). This approach supports insertion points in the document body.

Here's a working example of what is needed for the second approach:

**index.html** -- add an element that styles will be inserted after

```
...
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="custom-jss-insertion-point"></div>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
...
```

**App.js** -- Tell JSS about the custom insertion point

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "jss";
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const jss = create({
  ...jssPreset(),
  // Define a custom insertion point that JSS will look for when injecting the styles into the DOM.
  insertionPoint: document.getElementById("custom-jss-insertion-point")
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <div className="App">
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Hello
        </Button>
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit jss insertion point within body]

This results in the styles being added as shown in the image below:
[image]

If you render the insertion point element using React, you need to ensure that the element exists before you try to call `document.getElementById("custom-jss-insertion-point")` while configuring JSS. If it is possible to do so, I would recommend rendering the insertion point element outside of React (as in the example) to avoid order-of-operations complications.